# PHP changed Parameter redirect by htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, parameters

I want to redirect my dynamic links to new parameter.

My Old code for Files:

```
https://www.example.com/index.php?a=browse&b=category&id=[DYNAMIC ID IN NUMBERS]
```

I want new for Files :

```
https://www.example.com/index.php?a=downloads&b=file&id=[DYNAMIC ID IN NUMBERS]
```

How to do that in `.htaccess`?

My current `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

To redirect the "old" URL to the "new" whilst maintaining the "old" *dynamic id*, try the following *before* your existing directives:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^a=browse&b=category&id=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)$ https://www.example.com/$1?a=downloads&b=file&id=%1 [R=301,L]
```

The `$1` backreference simply matches `index.php` and saves repetition.

The `%1` (as opposed to `$1`) is a backreference to the captured pattern in the preceding *CondPattern* ie. the value of the `id` URL parameter.